# Django : Filter on the basis of dictionary values

Tags: python, django, orm

I have my django admin as --

`User                   Name                 City     Number
John_Lincoln_roma_1.0   John_Lincoln_roma    roma     1.0 
Eddie_paul_roma_1.1     Eddie_paul_roma      roma     1.1
Shin_roma_1.2           Shin_roma            roma     1.2 
Sinclair_madrid_1.0     Sinclair_madrid      madrid   1.0
Jessie_madrid_1.1       Jessie_madrid        madrid   1.1`

I want to apply query which should return me the `User` on the basis of Max number which is 1.2 & 1.1 and the record it should give me are Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1

Below is the snippet which I tried -

`some_object.values('name').annotate(number=Max('number')).order_by()`

Getting the result as -

`result = [{'number': u'1.2', 'name': u'Shin_roma'}, {'number': u'1.1', 'name': u'Jessie_madrid'},`

`print type(result)
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

I want a query or filter that returns the `User` based on filtering the dictionary values which is in `result`.

Basically I want to group by on the basis of CITY and on the basis of City Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1 is Max. So it should return me the User with Max number on order of City

I tried something like this which I didn't get the result (I know this is wrong) -

`result.filter(result__number="number",result__city="city")`

Gone through the stackoverflow but didn't get the solution.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. I hope the above is clear.

Thanks.!

Comment: Can you explain further: how should your result look like?

Comment: Shouldn't the query also give you `Eddie_paul_roma_1.1` if you're looking for 1.2 and 1.1? You need to be more specific with what information you start with and what you want the result to be.

Comment: @ger.s.brett Yes. I mentioned. I want User data.and it should return me Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1 record.
Result [<Shin_roma_1.2>,<Jessie_madrid_1.1>]. This record I want. Might be my query is wrong or you want to correct.

Comment: @Don Can you correct me ? where is the mistake that it is not returning me the record of User with max number i.e I want  Result [<Shin_roma_1.2>,<Jessie_madrid_1.1>].

Comment: @Code_10 I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Don I want to group by on the basis of CITY and on the basis of City Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1 is Max. So it should return me the User with Max number on order of City. Please let me know if that clears up your doubt

Answer (score 0):

here my model name is 'dummy', I have used 
    same attributes you have given and I am getting the result you have given.

```
obj=dummy.objects.values('user').order_by('-number','-name')[:2]
>>> obj
<QuerySet [{'user': 'Shin_roma_1.2'}, {'user': 'Jessie_madrid_1.1'}]>
```

Comment: I have n number of records. So in that case I think your [:2] will be wrong. Isn't ?

Comment: "I want to apply query which should return me the User on the basis of Max number which is 1.2 & 1.1 and the record it should give me are Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1" --if you go my this statement if you apply Max function on number you will be retrieving only one record that is 'shin_roma_1.2' which is max in this case. But why are you taking second max ? which is 'Jessie_madrid_1.1' why not 'Eddie_paul_roma_1.1'  . if you need to order by  this is the only query by which you access 'user' with highest to decreasing

Comment: obj=dummy.objects.values('user').order_by('-number','-name')
>>> obj
<QuerySet [{'user': 'Shin_roma_1.2'}, {'user': 'Jessie_madrid_1.1'}, {'user': 'Eddie_paul_roma_1.1'}, {'user': 'Sinclair_madrid_1.0'}, {'user': 'John_Lincoln_roma_1.0'}]>

Comment: I want to group by on the basis of CITY and on the basis of City Shin_roma_1.2 and Jessie_madrid_1.1 is Max. So it should return me the User with Max number on order of City. Are you getting me now ?